# Getting 406, "Could not find acceptable representation" with Spring boot, WebFlux, and custom `Accept` header

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have a RESTful web service that uses a custom Accept header to do versioning.

Adding the custom header value to the `produces` attribute in the `@RequestMapping` annotation as described on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-custom-media-type) doesn't seem work in a webflux enabled project.

Doing the same thing in a different non-webflux Springboot webservice works as expected.

When sending the custom header from a REST client, to the webflux enabled project I get an error that looks like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-03T21:25:34.885+0000",
    "path": "/some/resource/ID",
    "status": 406,
    "error": "Not Acceptable",
    "message": "Could not find acceptable representation"
}
```

Comment: Your question is missing key parts to understand what's going on. Please provide code snippets showing your webflux configuration, webflux controller, HTTP request headers, webflux debug logs.

Comment: Given, there's not enough details, perhaps this may relate to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306194/springboot-webflux-cannot-return-application-xml