# SpringBoot Webflux cannot return application/xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-webflux, jackson-dataformat-xml

In my reactive REST API I'm trying to return an `XML` response. However, I always get a `JSON`, namely `406 NOT_ACCEPTABLE`. Any idea why?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/xml", produces = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
public class RestApi {
    @GetMapping(path = "/get")
    public Publisher<ResponseEntity> get() {
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_XML).body(new Datta("test")));
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/post", consumes = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public Publisher<ResponseEntity<Datta>> post(@RequestBody Datta datus) {
        datus.setTitle(datus.getTitle() + "!");
        return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(APPLICATION_XML).body(datus));
    }
}
```

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>   Expected :application/xml
>   Actual   :application/json;charset=UTF-8

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.7.RELEASE"
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.9.8"
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

These are the links to my REST [controller](https://github.com/maslick/fluxish/blob/master/src/main/java/io/maslick/fluxish/RestApi.java) and a [unit test](https://github.com/maslick/fluxish/blob/master/src/test/java/io/maslick/fluxish/FluxishApplicationTests.java). Thanks!

Comment: afaik you should use the @RequestMapping(produces=APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) above the API-methods, not the Controller class. Probably changing your method-annotations to e.g.   @GetMapping(path = "/get", produces = APPLICATION_XML_VALUE) will do the trick.

Comment: @Gewure no, it doesn't matter where you put it (class or method level), try to checkout the code https://github.com/maslick/fluxish and play with it yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, `jackson-dataformat-xml` [does not yet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20256) support XML Marshalling in WebFlux. As for now I see two possibilities:

1. Either add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web` on the classpath (there should be both *starter-web* and *starter-webflux*). However, this will only work with Servlet 3.1 runtimes (e.g. Tomcat).
2. Or if you want a fully fledged reactive web server (e.g. Netty) [use](https://www.dariawan.com/tutorials/java/using-jaxb-java-11/) xml marshalling from JAXB (`Jaxb2XmlEncoder` and `Jaxb2XmlDecoder`):

**build.gradle**:

```
sourceCompatibility = '11'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    // Java 11 removed these Java EE modules
    implementation "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    implementation "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2"

    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok"
}
```

**POJO**:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlRootElement
public class Datta {
    private String title;
}
```

Mind the 3 `javax.xml.bind` dependencies (you don't need these for `Java 8`) and the `@XmlRootElement` annotation. This solution works right away, however if you want further customization, implement your own `WebFluxConfigurer`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.registerDefaults(false);
        configurer.customCodecs().decoder(new Jaxb2XmlDecoder());   // <- here
        configurer.customCodecs().encoder(new Jaxb2XmlEncoder());   // <- here

    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/maslick/fluxish/tree/jaxb) is the link to the source code.