# Issue with response as APPLICATION_XML while using Spring webflux

Tags: xml, jaxb, spring-webflux

Following code works fine while returning JSON

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> postUpload(ServerRequest request) {

final Flux<Object> stringFlux = request.body(BodyExtractors.toParts())
            .flatMap(filePart -> filePart.content().map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                byte[] resMessage = new byte[1024];
                resMessage = helper.postUpload(bytes, headers);
                String resposeMessage = new String(resMessage, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                return resposeMessage;
            }).doOnError(e -> LOGGER.error("Error on Processing file", e)));
            
    return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(stringFlux, Object.class);
    }
```

But I get error if I return XML (replaced JSON in the last line with XML)

```
return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(stringFlux, Object.class);
```

Error message I get is
**Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=java.lang.Object**

Reviewed similar question at  [SpringBoot Webflux cannot return application/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306194/springboot-webflux-cannot-return-application-xml) and [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916221/javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-mo), accordingly changed my code to use JAXB

```
JAXBContext jc = null;
            try {
                jc =JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{com.apple.ist.realestate.sm.rqm.model.TestXml.class});
            } catch (JAXBException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
return ServerResponse.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(BodyInserters.fromValue(jc));
```

Still I get the unsupported error: **Content type 'application/xml' not supported for bodyType=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl**

Any help or discussion appreciated.

Comment: why are the specifying the type of the object you want to serialise as `Object` instead of it's actual type?

Comment: as mentioned, you clearly want to return a string in the response, why not use string instead of object.