# Spring webflux rest service xml formatting

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, xml-formatting

I have written a reactive webflux rest service with Spring Boot that returns XML. I would like the XML to be formatted, which you would do with 'marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);' if you did the marshalling yourself.

I have been searching the web for a way to set this property in Spring Boot or any other way to convince the marshaller that the XML should be formatted, but can't find a solution. Anybody have any idea?

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306194/springboot-webflux-cannot-return-application-xml

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpringBoot Webflux cannot return application/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306194/springboot-webflux-cannot-return-application-xml)